# Dynamic Product Images

Tags: product, product-images

I am creating dynamic CSS graphics that will update as the user adjusts various options on the product (size and color mainly). This replaces the product's image and it works great from a UI/UX standpoint. It's fast and the display updates instantly.

The problem is that these images will need to still become actual raster graphics at some point (for display in email, cart, shopping feeds, etc).

I am debating whether to use PHP-GD to build these images as needed or to instead render only the CSS version to its own URL and then convert this to an image with one of the many available methods for saving CSS/markup into a raster image (ie. Phantom.js).

**1. How can I set a product image's URL so that it points to a controller instead of an uploaded file?**

**2. How can I then add these generated images to the product's image cache?**